# Can I understand which hardware failure caused my system to restart?

Tags: 14.04, cpu, gpu

I have seen similar questions asked here about how one can know what cause the system to restart.

However if I'm not mistaken, they wouldn't show specifically which hardware failed or if it was caused by CPU because of high temperatures or even GPU.

So my question is, is there a way that I can check for the cause of system restart?

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect the system's logs for the boot-before-last (the one that ended with the crash) with

```
journalctl -b -1
```

HOWEVER, not all failures get logged. Some failures cause the system to go down so quickly that logs don't get written - overheat is one.

Comment: I installed sysmd, but now I get : journalctl: invalid option -- '1'

Comment: OK, It only shows logs for Sep 25th only. It seems there is no log for previous days. (I'm using with and without -b switch)

Comment: When plain `journalctl` shows normal log chatter then the `kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset` (beginning of reboot) message, I assume Temperature or Power problems. CPU and Memory problems usually get logged.

Answer (score 1):

There are two syslog files that you can check for error messages... `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/syslog.1`.

If you know about what day/time the restart occurred, you can `more /var/log/syslog` or `more /var/log/syslog.1` looking for errors occurring in that time frame.

If you don't remember what day/time the restart occurred, you can `grep` for things like `grep temp /var/log/syslog*`, or `grep error /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: Thank you very much : What exactly should I be looking for? This happened to me several hours ago, so I should be able to check the time frame the incident happen. However I have no idea what should I be looking for. is there something that stands out when a failure occurs?

Comment: @Coderx7 Look for the reboot sequence, and then look at the log just before the reboot if you see any error messages.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but I noticed the logs dont have any record for the time the restart happened. at least this is what looks to me.
The restart happened around 2-3 pm, and yet looking at these, I dont see anything special: https://paste.ee/p/C7ftF
the logs are not chronologically ordered, the log for Sep 23 15:00 is located after Sep 23 18:31!!(line 1096) .
What could this mean? were there no hardware issues or it didnt get logged?

Comment: I reviewed your syslog. Is `secure boot` disabled in your BIOS? The nvidia driver is tainting the kernel. Do you have the latest/correct nvidia driver installed? It's asking you to install `nss-myhostname`. If you have a r8168 ethernet card (sudo lshw -C network)  using the r8169 driver, you need to install `r8168-dkms`.